# Get Parameter From URL And Post In Javascript On Click

Tags: javascript

Thanks for taking time to improve my code. I have a Google Ads link which when clicked contain "Gclid" at the end.
URL: https://google.com/?gclid=RandomGclidHere.

My Javascript Code is,

```
document.getElementById("Australia").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "https://google.com/au.php?gclid=ENTERGCLIDHERE";
};
document.getElementById("New Zealand").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "https://google.com/nz.php?gclid=ENTERGCLIDHERE";
};
document.getElementById("United States").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "https://google.com/us.php?gclid=ENTERGCLIDHERE";
};
```

I have a drop down on the page which contain 3 options, Australia, New Zealand & USA. The visitor is redirected based on drop-down selection. I want to get the "Gclid" from URL and post the "Gclid" to the URLS through Javascript.

Please guide!

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) help you?

Answer (score 1):

If by dropdown you mean a select, I would suggest putting the event listener on the select itself, and using its value:

```
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', handleCountryChange)

function handleCountryChange(event) {
const countrySelected = event.target.value
const countryDict = { 'australia': 'au', 'country': 'code'}
const countryCode = countryDict[countrySelected]
const gclid = 'ENTERGCLIDHERE'
const googleUrl = `https://google.com/${countryDict}.php?gclid=${gclid}`

window.location.href = googleUrl
}
```

Having less event listeners is usually desired.

Comment: Hi Larsw,

1. I want to grab the parameter from URL: '?gclid=RandomGclidHere.'
2. When the Visitor select the Country Name 'AU, NZ or US', I want to add the grabbed parameter (in this case google click id) and post at the end of the URL in place of 'ENTERGCLIDHERE' , https://google.com/us.php?gclid=ENTERGCLIDHERE.